# Multiple Databases in 1 Django Project

Tags: python, sql, django, mongodb, django-models

I am planning to develop a AI-Enabled Stock Market Project using Django & Tensorflow

**For Clients, I plan to use MSSQL**

**For Stock Tickers, I plan to use MongoDB**

How do I do it in Django?

I am in Planning stage

Comment: Read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Django is good for using a single database. I strongly advise you to use an API. This allows you to connect to as many databases as you want. You can use Django Rest API if you want.

However you can find this documentation : [docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/)